# Exchange 2010 on Windows Server 2008 R2 -

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, installation

I tried to install MS Exchange 2010 on Windows Server 2008 R2. The installation went fine i.e. the wizard went through the process successfully.

Now when I run the get-exchangeserver inside the EMS get the following error. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
PS C:\Users\administrator.ROOT> Get-ExchangeServer
The term 'Get-ExchangeServer' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:19
+ Get-ExchangeServer <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-ExchangeServer:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Have you rebooted after the installation finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it was the IIS the stopped due to conflict with protocols. it kept shutting it down for some weird reason it is when i stopped sharepoint web service when it started working.

Answer (score 1):

More of a server thing I'd say, in any case...

> > Anonymous: Chances are you're running the script from a PowerShell prompt, instead of the Exchange Management Shell. Run the script from EMS and it should work.

(From comment in http://www.expta.com/2009/05/powershell-script-to-get-exchange.html)

Happy admin stuff.

Comment: Not quite, I am running it from EMS.